# what's the optimal chunk size for laravel

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, laravel-5

I've been working on a web app that reads some data from a remote server on it's own server side. I'm using Laravel, and initially thought it would be easier to develop my own php file with methods to connect to the remote DB. What this php does: fetch the data from the remote server (postgreSQL) and insert that into Laravel using Eloquent. Here's some code snippets.

```
try {
    $dal = connect();
    //... some validations not relevant to the question
    $result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
    $data = (array_values(pg_fetch_all($result)));
    $chunkOfData = array_chunk($data, 1000);
    foreach ($chunkOfData as $chunk) {
        insertChunkToDB($chunk);
    }
    closeDB($dal);
} catch(exception $e){
    Log::error('Error syncing both databases, more details: '.$e);
    exit(1);
}
```

My question focuses on the array_chunk.

I had to do this because the php crashed with "out of memory error". I used the insertChunk function so the garbage collector would clean the data that's already been inserted. Notice this code is fully functioning (as far as I know).

But... if the pg_fetch_all already retrieved the data... isn't it already in memory? why didn't the program crash then? As a side question how fast can Laravel input it's data? Would using smaller chunks (like 100) cause the program to slow down due to jumping between iterations/garbage collecting? What would be the splitting number to make things fastest?

Oh, by the way this is the function

```
function insertChunkToDB($chunk){
    foreach ($chunk as $element) {
        $object = json_decode(json_encode($element), FALSE);
        insertObjectToDB($object);
    }
}
```

The encode/decode is done so I can do this

```
function insertObjectToDB($element){
    $LaravelModel = $element->id;
    $LaravelModel = $element->name; //and so on...
    $LaravelModel->save();    
}
```

When recording foreign keys I do a quick check to see if I have the corresponding value, and if not I quickly issue an extra query to the remote server to record that data in the corresponding table.